# Uninstalling hard deleted application from Windows7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Unfortunately, I have hard deleted the microsoft sql server folder present in program files folder. So now I need to uninstall the MSSQL server from my machine. I have tried but I got an error something like "The source folder is missing". For resolving this issue, I have manually deleted the MS SQL services using "sc delete" command and I have deleted the MSSQL entry from regedit file also. But still MS SQL server entry available in "Programs and Features" list. Please guide me for solving this issue even I can't able to re install the MSSQL server once again.

Thank you guys...

Gnanasuriyan A.

Comment: The simple solution would be to install it, then uninstall it, should clear up your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ramhound suggests it in comments, you could reinstall it and uninstall it in a proper way to solve your problem. It would also make sure you didn't forget something to remove in the process.

Now if you just want the entry to be removed from "Programs and Features", you can use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to delete it explicitly from the list.

[image: CCleaner uninstall screenshot]

Comment: The data would be gone, but the registery enteries would exist, which would cause havok to amy program expecting SQL Server to actually be in a working state after detecting it was installed.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, it's not really the recommended way to do, and only a second option in my answer. The appropriate way is of course to use the normal uninstaller (even if that's not a guarantee to clean everything)